# Behavioral Voltage Source in SIMPLIS

Tags: circuit-analysis, ltspice, simulation

I'd like to make a voltage source that clamps my waveform to 1 V. In LTSpice I can easily use a behavioral voltage source and program it accordingly.

There is a ramp that is exponentially increasing to 3 V and I want to clamp it at 1 V. In LTSPICE I can use a behavioral voltage source and program it as IF(V(SSRAMP)<REF, SSRAMP, REF).

Reference is 1 V.

Does anyone have any idea? What is the similar method if I want to do this in SIMPLIS?

I can't seem to find a similar voltage source in SIMPLIS.

Comment: Use arbitrary source.

Comment: I have tried to find the arbitrary source but couldn't find it in the components.

Comment: Doesn't SIMPLIS have a VCVS with programmable limits?  You could just put that on your ramp if I'm remembering correctly.

Comment: @JohnD Thank you. That works.

Comment: @JohnD Make that an answer, as short as it may be (a picture or link to the documentation might also help).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thanks, done- I was busy at the time and couldn't remember or look up the details hence the comment, but just added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIMPLIS has a voltage-controlled voltage source with saturation limits on the output.

I couldn't find much documentation on it, but [here's](https://www.simplis.com/version84/whats-new) a link to the description. In the latest version it can be ideal or non-ideal limiting as shown by the graph below, also from the link above.

[image]